# Undefined variables in cfg in /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/mamp/index.php

Tags: php, localhost, mamp

Without seemingly having actually changed anything  my localhost seems to have died.  MAD lights up on mamppro, but I can't access my databases via either phpmyadmin or sequelpro, and the sites are WSOD.

multiple errors showing:
Undefined variable: cfg in /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/mamp/index.php on line …

So I'm dead in the water with this.

I recently upgraded to both MAMP pro 3.07.3 (from 2.X) and Yosemite (now 10.10.1 (14B25)).

But  things have been humming for a few weeks - with the exception of a common issue that renames my computer name myComputer (2), then (3) etc. This was only causing issues on codekit however, and have bene able to work around.  I've also done catch up mac maintenance after this issue: rebuilt disk directory, ran periodic maint scripts, cleared caches, repaired permissions etc - no change.  I have exhaustive permissions but don't have a clue what i would restore to fix this.

Explicit logged errors viewable at:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/hbpfx24vty4235m/php_error%20-%20undefined%20variables.log?dl=0

Comment: ACTUALLY  - might just have fixed this  - an unset mamp settings - all a bit weird  -will update again